# Is there any API available from Monster for searching job

Tags: api, service

Is there any API available from Monster to search job based on keyword, category, location, etc. I got the below link after some googling

http://xml.monster.com/doc/

But there is no specification about job search.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated..

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.programmableweb.com/api/monster-web-services-toolkit http://integrations.monster.com/doc/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: `"And how did you find us?"` "With this application I wrote that analyzes job openings, compares them to my skillset, and sends an application." `"When can you start?"`

Comment: mamoo, thanks for your reply. 

i have already seen these links and these are for job posting instead of job search.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of the date that this question was initially asked, they did not have a public API.

At that point, there were [Yahoo Pipes that use their RSS](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/search?r=source%3Amonster.com) feed, though.

Here's a [site](http://www.nealgrosskopf.com/extras/monster/) that generates links to RSS feeds on Monster.com, since it doesn't seem like there are regular RSS links available after you do a search, as there are on Indeed & SimplyHired..

As of the initial date of posting, it may have been possible to generate RSS feed links through the advanced search feature on Monster.com, but only if you have an account, since then you can save searches. This was described in [How to Use Monster to Find a Job](http://websearch.about.com/od/jobsearchengines/qt/monster-jobs.htm).

See the answer by Pedro Pereira, below. It appears that they may have an API as of 2013.

For more on that, you could research [their documentation](https://partner.monster.com/integrations-solutions).

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be one. Check their soap box at: 
http://integrations.monster.com/Toolkit/RealtimePosting/Sample/Inventory_Query/Jobs_All for an example on how to view all jobs. There is also a request JobPosting info http://integrations.monster.com/Toolkit/RealtimePosting/Sample/Queries/Get_JobPostingInfo .
With a combination you could get jobs and info I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Monster provides an [RSS Feed](http://rss.jobsearch.monster.com/rssquery.ashx?q=Web%20Developer).

It's accessible through the Monster site's [standard search](http://jobsearch.monster.com/).

Once you do the search you'll see the rss icon link in the header to the left of "Classic Search"

Answer (score 1):

check out the [Monster Developer Page](http://partner.monster.com/developers)