# Job listing specification and/or query standards?

Tags: xml, rest, xsd, standards

I find myself in the position where I need to find a way to get job listings from someone else's system into my own. I don't control the other system, but I'll be collaborating with their developers to figure out how this will work. I've already done some theoretical work in this direction (no code yet), but before I get too deep, I want to make sure that I'm not reinventing too many wheels. To that end…

- Is anyone aware of a standardized format in XML (or similar) for job listings? Searching the internet for such a thing has not had any promising results so far.
- Is anyone aware of a standard for doing RESTful queries (or similar) of job listings? For my own needs, this can probably be pretty basic (maybe "return an updated listing for this UUID if its ETag is different than this" or "tell me all listings posted since this timestamp"), but if there were something more complex available, that'd be cool too.
- Failing the above two points, is there anyone or anywhere that would be interested in collaborating on working on such standards?

Answer (score 1):

I found this standards group called [HR-XML](http://www.hr-xml.org/) that is at least trying to implement some sort of standards for various HR related activities.

One of our integrations applies their *CV/Resume* standard which seems to be a bit more common.

Based on this [diagram](http://www.hr-xml.org/?page=DownloadLandingPage) on their site, it seems their *Recruiting* standards section also applies to **job boards**. The double arrow seems to indicate that they include standards for posting jobs as well as receiving CV/Resumes, but unfortunately it seems that you need to be a member of the standards group to be able to see it. I'm not sure how that promotes their standards.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a standardized format would be Atom. They're time-sensitive enough that a feed model is probably the best way to go (and the most standardized, to boot). I would certainly only be interested in consuming such a service that way (perhaps after one HTML form to set up the feed query).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't think Atom will be of great help here. I'm looking for standards specific to job listings, and Atom is just too general in that regard.

Comment: You can look, but I don't think you'll find. Just like the standard format for an e-commerce site is HTML, the standard for job sites seems to be Atom/RSS (and HTML, as well). Juju uses RSS (see http://www.job-search-engine.com/publisher/spec/); Monster uses HTML (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150336/is-there-any-api-available-from-monster-for-searching-job); Indeed uses HTML and RSS (http://www.indeed.com/tools/jobseeker/). No theoretical specification can be more "standard" than what most sites do in reality.